# Why do we say azan in the ear of a newborn?

Tags: adhan, baby

I am having baby in few months and I want to know the truth behind saying azan in the ear of a new born.  Please provide references from Quran and Hadith.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the hadith, which proves that we must say azan in ear of new born:

Sunan of Abu-Dawood Hadith 5086  Narrated byAbu Rafi'

> I saw the Messenger of Allah (saws) uttering the call to prayer
>   (Adhan) in the ear of al-Hasan ibn Ali when Fatimah gave birth to him.

Also, you should give him small amount of sweet, chewed by you or some elder,and let it tasted by the baby. that is sunnah as well

Comment: Should it be full azan or just a start/part of it?

Comment: I understand the azan part but giving something sweet to a new born can be risky. Don't you think so? Is it mandatory too?

Comment: whatever is in Quran or hadith, it can never harm us in any situation. thats why even medical science has just proved that giving sweet to a child after birth saves from serious risk of strokes, which mostly happen at that time

Answer (score 2):

It's a kind of *تلقین* *Talqin* . Talqin means indoctrinate, drum into...

It's mostly known to be done at the time death. As the person has just been placed into his grave and is now to be questioned about his life, wealth, youth, Imam, what he loved, his desires. See [here](https://en.islamkingdom.com/Fatawa/Funerals_and_Zakah/Completion_of_the_Chapter_on_Funerals_/Permissible_and_impermissible_acts_to_be_done_for_the_deceased_and_his_family/Reciting_Talqin_after_death) and [here](http://www.darulfatwa.org.au/en/reciting-quran-for-the-dead-and-talqeen/)

"Many of our companions said that it is likeable (mustahab) to make talqin to the dead Muslim after his or her burial. From those companions [An-Nawawiyy’s] is Al-Qadi Husayn in his Ta'liq, his friend Abu Sa'id Al-Mutawalli in his book At-Tatimmah, Ash-Shaykh Imam Abul Fath Nasr bin Ibrahim bin Nasr Al-Maqdisiyy, Imam Abul Qasim Ar-Rafi'iyy and others. Qadi Husayn also conveyed that matter from way of his companions. As to the exact phrase Ash-Shaykh Nasr said the following: “Once one finishes from burying him, they stand at his head and they say “Ya fulan ibn fulan” [calling him]! Remember the covenant by which you exited this world; the testification that there is no God but Allah who has no partners and the testification that Muhammad is the messenger and slave of Allah, also remember that Judgment Day is coming no doubt and that Allah resurrects those in the graves, say: ‘I have accepted that my Lord is Allah, that Islam is my religion, that Muhammad sallallahu 'alayhi wa sallam is a true Prophet, that the Ka'bah is the true direction for prayer, that the Qur’an is my guider and that the Muslims are brethren’. Testify that your Lord is Allah, there is no God but Him and that He is the Lord and Creator of the great Throne ('Arsh)”.

Additionally it has been meant to be done at the time of birth. 
What I see similar in both situations is weakness and importance of the moment. At death you're done with your life, you may have sinned and need aid and it's also very important moment of your entire being. At birth you're also weak and innocent and it's just the beginning so it's best to start off right.

Sunnis scholars mostly approve the Azan part but say the Iqama part is weak.

Shi'a scholars approve them both.

The reason for birth is also to indoctrinate, vaccinate the child spiritually so Satan would be shunned away and the child would be safe from fearing him( مستدرک ج3ص62)

The Azan is very important call, it conveys the core of our religions and seems understandable to instill it from the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

it's Not mentioned in any of the isalmic Hadith books except for Sunan Abu-Dawood. and with a very week reference.

it's just a habit, people think it's better for a new born to hear azan as the first thing in the world.
ن ابن عباس رضي الله عنهما :( أن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم أذنّ في أذن الحسن بن علي يوم ولد وأقام في أذنه اليسرى ) **سلسلة الأحاديث الضعيفة** 1/331

Comment: the hadith is authentic. Sunan of Abu-Dawood Hadith 5086 Narrated byAbu Rafi'

    I saw the Messenger of Allah (saws) uttering the call to prayer (Adhan) in the ear of al-Hasan ibn Ali when Fatimah gave birth to him.

Comment: Hadith 5086 in Sunan Abu-Dawood is narrated by Abu Rafi' (and is *hasan* according to sunnah.com), but the hadith you quoted (and claim is weak) is different: Not only was it narrated by Ibn 'Abbas instead of Abu Rafi', the wording of the *matn* is different and I can't find it in Abu-Dawood at all.  What exactly is the reference for the hadith you quote?

Answer (score -1):

Narrated AbuRafi':
I saw the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) uttering the call to prayer (Adhan) in the ear of al-Hasan ibn Ali when Fatimah gave birth to him.
حَدَّثَنَا مُسَدَّدٌ، حَدَّثَنَا يَحْيَى، عَنْ سُفْيَانَ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنِي عَاصِمُ بْنُ عُبَيْدِ اللَّهِ، عَنْ عُبَيْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ أَبِي رَافِعٍ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، قَالَ رَأَيْتُ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم أَذَّنَ فِي أُذُنِ الْحَسَنِ بْنِ عَلِيٍّ - حِينَ وَلَدَتْهُ فَاطِمَةُ - بِالصَّلاَةِ ‏.‏
Grade   : Hasan (Al-Albani)   حسن   (الألباني)  حكم     :
Reference    : Sunan Abi Dawud 5105
In-book reference    : Book 43, Hadith 333
English translation  : Book 42, Hadith 508

Comment: References don't speak for themselves please consider elaborating your answer with something of your own!